# Execute remote SQL script with linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 2 servers in a workgroup called "workgroup".

- Server A is `W2012R2` with SQL Server 2012.
- Server B is `W2012R2` with other application. SQLCMD Utility has been installed on server B.

I'm using local account, SQL service is start by local account. I can connect to the SQL server from B to A. I can launch query without difficulty. When I launch my SQL script, I get the following error:

```
E:\Batch\Script>sqlcmd -S YMSQL01 -i test.sql
```

> Changed database context to 'PROD'.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1,
>   Server YMSQL01, Procedure V_C_Prod, Line 3 The OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "C_PROD" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Server YMSQL01, Procedure V_C_Prod, Line 3
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB .12.0" for linked server "C_PROD".

As you can see, it seems that I cannot query on a view. This view is from a linked server which is connected to an Excel file (located on server B). I have installed the same ODBC driver on server B but I get the same error.

My SQL script:

```
Use PROD
Go

Merge dbo.conc  AS t
using V_C_Prod as s
ON (t.CodeComptable=s.[Code Comptable])
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    t.[Marque]=s.[Marque]
    ,t.[CodeHolding] = s.[Code HOLDING]
    ,t.[Email1]=s.[Email Principal]
    ,t.[CP]=s.[CP]
    ,t.[Ville]=s.[Ville]
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT VALUES (
    s.[Marque]
    ,s.[Code HOLDING]
    ,s.[Code Comptable]
    ,s.[Email Principal]
    ,s.[CP]
    ,s.[Ville];
Go
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, the script you are running works fine on server B? I.e. you can access the linked server pointing to the excel file from server B?

Comment: Yes if i copy the script into SQL Management Studio on server A, it is working fine. I think the problem is from linked server. I can't make a query from server B to the linked server. I got the same error message as you can find in the topic.

Comment: I think your question is too vague and does not describe the problem you are experiencing properly. *"I can launch query without difficulty."* > Where are you launching the query from? *"When I launch my SQL script"* > Where are you launching this SQL script from? *"[...] it seems that I cannot query on a view."* > There is no mention of a view in the error message, nor did you mention anything about a view up to that point. You need to be more specific in your question. Otherwise I don't see you getting any decent answers.

Comment: Ok i will reformule my problem. How can i make a query on a linked server stored into server A from server B. I think there is some option to configure for that.

Comment: After several test, my problem is on the linked server. I can do all query on database from server B to server A but if i make a query on the linked server, i've got an error message. If i do the same on server A, it is working fine.